# show only 0-90% or 0-95% percentile

Tags: r, statistics

Here is my code and plot results, dues to some outliers, the x-axis is very long. Is there a simple method which I can filter `df$foo` by only 0-90% or 0-95% percentile in R, so that I can plot only normal values? Thanks.

```
df <- read.csv('~/Downloads/foo.tsv', sep='\t', header=F, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
names(df) <- c('a', 'foo', 'goo')
df$foo <- as.numeric(df$foo)
goodValue <- df$foo
summary(goodValue)
hist(goodValue,main="Distribution",xlab="foo",breaks=20)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this is what you're looking for?

```
a = c(rnorm(99), 50) #create some data 
quant <- as.numeric(quantile(a, c(0, 0.9))) #get 0 and 0.9 quantile
hist(a[a > quant[1] & a < quant[2]]) #histogram only data within these bounds
```

Comment: Thanks Warner for the idea and vote up. I think your solution only works for normal distribution? For any other distributions, any solutions? BTW, I think I can write a function to calculate 90% percentile given any set of data (i.e. could be of any type distributions), in this question, I am just asking if any built-in methods.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi, vote up for your reply. I know what quantile mean, I mean in the code, it is using `rnorm`, I think it calculate quantile based on the assumption of normal distribution of the data?

Comment: @LinMa I used `rnorm` just to create some data. `quantile` will work on a vector regardless of its distribution. @ZheyuanLi I agree with your shorter version of the code. I was just illustrating what it would look like if a upper and lower bound were chosen.

Comment: Thank Warner, vote up and sorry for the late response. I read your code again and it is my mis-understanding in the past. One more question, in R help, quantile function has a description -- "The generic function quantile produces sample quantiles corresponding to the given probabilities.", I am wondering what means sample quantiles? Shouldn't quantile based on the whole dataset?

Comment: In that definition "sample quantiles" _is_ referring to your data set. For example with `quantile(0:10)`. Your data set is ` 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10` but it is assumed to be a sample or subset of a whole population of `0:10`s. This definition takes into account the idea that all of our data is just a sample and that `quantile` can be used to make generalizations about the whole population using what is given in the data set. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Warner, vote up for your reply. I just want to confirm in your example, `quantile(0:10)`, function `quantile` uses all numbers from `1` to `10` when calculate percentile? Other than a sample from `1` to `10` to calculate percentile?

Comment: Yes that is correct. `quantile(1:10)` is calculating the quantiles of all numbers 1 through 10.

Comment: Thanks Warner, vote up for your reply. Just curious how did quantile calculated, if we only have a few samples other than a complete known distribution (`rnorm` in your example), is `quantile` calculated in an estimation other than accurate way?

Comment: @LinMa I recommend further reading on quantiles. I think the wikipedia article is pretty well written and can help answer the kinds of questions you are having. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile#Estimating_quantiles_from_a_sample

Comment: Thanks Warner, vote up. I studied the link and confused by statement "the estimate for the k-th q-quantile", the confusion is, I think when we say quantile, we say 90%, 95% quantile, in this sense 90/95 is `q`, but what is `k` here?

Comment: `k` is just a name we give to a specific quantile we are interested in. Note how the article says that `k` is an integer where `0 < k < q`. `q` is how we choose to partition our data. The `quantile` function in R computes `q=5` quantiles. Using my example of `quantile(1:10)` if we wanted to choose the 4th quantile (`k=4`) we would get `7.75`

Comment: I see, thanks Warner. I always use 100 quantile so it is why I am confused. Vote up. I studied the wiki you posted, it mentioned in what kinds of tools or programming language, how many approaches of quantile estimation based on sample are supported, but it never mentioned what algorithm is used to estimate quantile? Maybe I read it wrong? Appreciate for your further comments and please feel free to correct me. :)

Comment: Thanks for the patience to help, have a good day Warner. Mark your reply as answer.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you wanted to examine the diamonds. (I don't have your data)

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
diamonds %>% ggplot() + geom_histogram(aes(x = price))
```

[image]

You might decide to examine the deciles of your data, and since the tail probability is not of interest to you, you might throw away the top uppermost decile. You could do that as follows, with a free scale so that you can see what is happening within each decile.

```
diamonds %>% mutate(ntile = ntile(price, 10)) %>% 
  filter(ntile < 10) %>%
  ggplot() + geom_histogram(aes(x = price)) + 
  facet_wrap(~ntile, scales = "free_x")
```

**But be cautious** although seeing your data in a much finer granularity has its benefits, notice how you could almost barely tell that your data is roughly exponentially distributed (with a heavy tail, as commodities price data often are).

[image]

Comment: Thanks shayaa, vote up. For this line, `filter(ntile < 10) %>%`, what does `%` mean? Is it your command line prompt? I am using R Studio so a bit confused. Thanks.

Comment: The function `%>%` is a special function from the `magrittr` package which is imported by the `dplyr` package. It mean take the precendent function from before the `%>%` and supply it as the first argument to the antecedent function after the `%>%`. For example, in this case, it takes the diamonds data set and supplies it as the first argument to the `mutate` function, which takes `.data` as the first argument.

Comment: It can be read as "and then", e.g., take diamonds "and then" add a column specifying which decile the price is, "and then" remove the largest decile, "and then" plot price it as a histogram along a free x axis.

Comment: Thanks shayaa, vote up for your both replies and sorry for the late response. I never used `mutate` function and tried help, `? mutate
No documentation for ‘mutate’ in specified packages and libraries:`, it seems I do not have `mutate` function, is it from another package?

Comment: Another high level question is, what do you think your method differences between the method from Warner? Thanks.

Comment: It differs in the sense that removing 10% outliers will not change the histogram too much, so you won't lose too much of the data structure. I am plotting each decile separately, so 10 subsets.

Comment: Thanks shayaa, what is the differences between using `quantile(a, c(0, 0.9))`, and your method `filter(ntile < 10)`, for the purpose of remove 10% outlier?

Comment: quantile calculates the numeric value of the quantiles and filter is a function, which given a logical expression, selects the rows which match `TRUE`. In this case, it chooses the data which is not in the top decile. In the other answer, the part of the code which does this is the stuff inside the `hist()` on the last line.

Comment: Thanks shayaa, vote up. A stupid question, is `ntile` some R function in some package? I looked through but cannot find it out.

Comment: Thanks shayaa, vote up. I am able to install `dplyr` successfully and run your samples without any issues. A bit confused by `mutate`, in R help document, it is said about argument for `mutate` --  "
.data A tbl. All main verbs are S3 generics and provide methods for tbl_df, tbl_dt and tbl_sql. ", I am confused about what is `.data`? Does it mean input parameter of `mutate` must have some column called `data`? And also what means `tbl` here? Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just read this vignette. It will do more justice than I can in less than 500 chars. https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html

Comment: Thanks shayaa, vote up. For this link you referred, I have no issues. Actually my issue is from your comments, " it takes the diamonds data set and supplies it as the first argument to the `mutate` function, which takes `.data` as the first argument. ", I am confused what is `.data` here? Thanks.